# JavaScript accordion in Omeka

Tags: javascript, omeka

I'm trying to create accordion buttons in my Omeka site so I found some code from W3Schools to adapt. I was able to get this to work when testing it out in an HTML doc with the JavaScript inside < script > tags but now that I've put that code in its own .js file to load into the page's head my buttons aren't working and I'm getting the following error: TypeError: panel is null.

Below is the code in my .js file:

```
/*
 * Script for accordion buttons
 */

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { 

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
});
```

And this is the CSS I've used:

```
 /* --- Accordion Menu Buttons --- */

.accordion {
    background-color: #A4C4E9 !important;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 75%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #999 !important;
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    width: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<p><button class="accordion">Section 1</button></p>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: and where is the `HTML`, `panel` is null means it cant find the element you might have to add the code the way you are actually using

Comment: I've added the HTML code I'm using for the buttons and panels

Comment: added an answer see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `max-height` property for the `.panel` class and you are trying to set the `display:block` or `none` via javascript you should set the `maxHeight` via using the `scrollHeight` of the `div.panel` or either use `display:none` inside the `.panel` class instead of `max-height` property.

The [**`Element.scrollHeight`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) read-only property is a measurement of the height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow.

See a demo below

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

      /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
      to highlight the button that controls the panel */
      this.classList.toggle("active");

      /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling; //.classList.toggle('active');

      if (panel.style.maxHeight == "") {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = "";
      }
    });
  }


});
```

```css
/* --- Accordion Menu Buttons --- */

.accordion {
  background-color: #A4C4E9 !important;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 75%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #999 !important;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel.active {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see that this code works when I run the snippet on here, but I've updated my files and I am still getting the error that the property 'style' of null can't be read at this line in the .js file: if (panel.style.maxHeight == "") { I think this may be an issue specific to Omeka, but being very new to JavaScript I'm not sure.

Comment: then update the post and add the whole page code or provide a paste bin i cant guess like this why with a working code you are unable to integrate at your end. @GayleS.

Comment: I don't have a whole page to add because of the way Omeka works. I have a number of files (several PHP, .js and style sheets) for my theme and then the actual site pages are built in the Omeka admin interface. You've been very helpful with the JavaScript though, thank you. I am posting what you've helped me with in Omeka's forums so hopefully one of their developers will be able to help me pinpoint why I am running into this error. Again, thank you for your help here!

Comment: no problem @GayleS. you are welcome do mark the answer as correct if it helped.